# unable unzip password protected .gz file in GCS bucket using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gzip, google-cloud-storage

Trying to unzip password protected file in GCS but getting error in below code. Below code work fine with normal .gz files but fails to unzip password protected files.

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
source_bucket = 'bucket'
source_bucket1 = storage_client.bucket(source_bucket)
blob = source_bucket1.blob("path/filename.gz")
zipbytes = io.BytesIO(blob.download_as_string())
        print(zipbytes)
        if is_zipfile(zipbytes):
            with ZipFile(zipbytes, 'r') as myzip:
                for contentfilename in myzip.namelist():
                    contentfile = myzip.read(contentfilename)
                    contentfilename = contentfilename[:-3]
                    blob1 = bucket.blob(contentfilename)
                    blob1.upload_from_string(contentfile)
                    print(f'File decompressed from {zipfilename_with_path} to {contentfilename}')
        blob.delete()
```

Comment: what error? ...

Comment: GZip (`.gz`) files are not Zip files and they don't support encryption.

Comment: have tried ```with ZipFile(blob, 'r') as zf:
            zf.printdir()
            print('Extracting all the files now...')
            zf.extractall(pwd=b'*********')   ``` as well but getting error as "Blob' object has no attribute 'seek'"

Comment: Did you try **myzip.setpassword("mypassword")**?

Comment: @JohnHanley, yes getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am able to read .csv.gz password protected file using below logic. All of this is done in memory. It has performance issue if the file is huge but works fine.

````
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        source_bucket = '<bucket-name>'
        source_bucket1 = storage_client.bucket(source_bucket)
        bukcet_folder = '/unzip'
        blob = source_bucket1.blob(path)
        zipbytes = io.BytesIO(blob.download_as_string())
        with ZipFile(zipbytes, 'r') as myzip:
            print("Inside the zipfiles loop")
            with myzip.open('filename.csv',pwd=b'password') as myfile:
                print("Inside zip 2 loop")
                contentfile = myfile.read()
                contentfilename = bucket_folder + destination_file_path
                blob1 = source_bucket1.blob(contentfilename)
                blob1.upload_from_string(contentfile)
              ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python, e.g. from a Cloud Function:

```
from google.cloud import storage
    from zipfile import ZipFile
    from zipfile import is_zipfile
    import io

    def zipextract(bucketname, zipfilename_with_path):

        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucketname)

        destination_blob_pathname = zipfilename_with_path
        
        blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_pathname)
        zipbytes = io.BytesIO(blob.download_as_string())

        if is_zipfile(zipbytes):
            with ZipFile(zipbytes, 'r') as myzip:
                for contentfilename in myzip.namelist():
                    contentfile = myzip.read(contentfilename)
                    blob = bucket.blob(zipfilename_with_path + "/" + contentfilename)
                    blob.upload_from_string(contentfile)

    zipextract("mybucket", "path/file.zip") # if the file is gs://mybucket/path/file.zip
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this logic is working on .gz files and not on password protected .gz files.